# vuejs how to iterate only part of array using v-for

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I've got an array as below:

```
return {
   items: [
      {active: true, text: 'text1'},
      {active: true, text: 'text2'},
      {active: true, text: 'text3'},
      {active: true, text: 'text4'},
      {active: true, text: 'text5'}
      ...
   ]
}
```

I want to iterate it in the DOM using `v-for` (easy) but I want to iterate them in two templates - first 3 elements of the array in template1 and the rest of elements in template2:

template1:

```
<template v-for="item in items">
   first 3 elements:
   {{item}}
</template>
```

template2:

```
<template v-for="item in items">
   the rest of elements: 
   {{item}}
</template>
```

How should I modify my `v-for` to make this work?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could either explicitly create two computed properties, based on the original `items` array, or just use a slice, for example:

```
<template v-for="item in items.slice(0, 3)">
```

and

```
<template v-for="item in items.slice(3)">
```

**N.B.** In both the above cases, it is assumed that `items` is always defined and  always an array. If you want to go with the inline approach but `items` could be undefined, then you could use `(items || []).slice()`.

Going with the computed property approach you could define something like:

```
computed: {
    itemsHead() {
        return this.items ? this.items.slice(0, 3) : [];
    },
    itemsTail() {
        return this.items ? this.items.slice(3) : [];
    }
}
```

Then refer to `itemsHead` and `itemsTail` in your templates.

Comment: `return this.items` would have to be `return this.items.length` in your ternary expression because `!![]` is `true`. Or did you want to check if `this.items` is `undefined`?

Comment: @connexo you are right. The same is with `v-for="item in items.slice(0, 3)"`, but Tom answered correct, because my arrays will have at least 3 elements. You can improve the answer if you wish to :)

Comment: @connexo the only problem is when `this.items` is not an array. If it's an empty array then that's not a problem.

Comment: Then use `Array.isArray(this.items)` as that will also clarify the intention.

Comment: Yep, or check that a property `slice` exists and is a function, or if it's a prop then specify `type: Array`, but I'm not sure any of this is in scope :)

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out another solution if you have a little more complex object e.g. if you have an outer loop and an inner loop where you only want to render something if a condition is true and you can't use a computed method as you are in an inner loop. Please correct me if that's not true regarding computed methods inside loops.

So here is my solution:

```
<div v-for="fooparent in fooparentarray">
<template v-for="foo in fooparent.foos">
<div v-if="foo.someproperty === 1">{{foo.someproperty}}</div>
</template>
</div>
```

As template is not rendered there will be nothing rendered for arrayelements that don't meet the condition. So a div is only rendered if the condition is met.